# Angular directive click function calling twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below are the two directive. My problem is that the function **addSectorAttributes** in my second directive is been fired twice on ng-click from project_subtypes.html.

```
      .directive('projectFilter', function($compile, $timeout){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'project_filter.html',
                link : function(scope,element, attr){
                   //getting data and fill the html from a service 
                },
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.addSubTypes = function (event,id) {
                      var ex = $(event.currentTarget);

                      var el = $compile( "<project-subtypes typeid="+id+" class='slide-content'></project-subtypes>" )( $scope );
                        ex.parent().append(el);

                    };
                }
            }
        })

       .directive('projectSubtypes', function($compile){
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: true,
                    templateUrl: 'project_subtypes.html',
                    link : function(scope,element,attr){
                            //getting data and fill the html from a service
                           var id = attr.typeid; 
sectorFiltering.getSectorSubTypes(id).success(function(data) {
                        scope.sector_subtypes = data.sector_subtypes;
                    });
                        });
                    },
                    controller: function ($scope) {
                        $scope.addSectorAttributes = function (event,id) {
                            console.log("teeest"); // called twice.....
                        };
                    }                        
                }
            })
```

project_subtypes.html

```
<li ng-repeat="subtype in substype.subtypes">
        <div layout='row' class='load-attributes' ng-click=" addSectorAttributes($event, subtype.id)"></div>
 </li>
```

Any help please....

Comment: Do you intend to repeat on li or div?

Comment: @Robert repeat on li

Comment: Can you add a code sample that shows the problem?

Comment: @Explore-X Can you explain your question properly?

Comment: Do you have any code in your link functions?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt Yes the link function just populate the data through a service

Comment: Can you please upload the code from the link function?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt Have updated

Comment: where are you calling the `$scope.addSubTypes` function?

Comment: At project_filter.html

Comment: Have the same problem. Do not use compile or link. Click handler is fired twice.

Answer (score 0):

If the directive function called twice if one time it does not give you the subtype.id and next time if it gives you subtype.id then you just only need to add condition in your directive like as below.

subtype.id&&addSectorAttributes($event, subtype.id)"

Regards,
Mahenrdra

Comment: where is the condition here

Comment: Am getting the id at both the times.